# How should I pass my data obtained in a service via HTTP in my component in Angular6

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular 6 and I can't pass data from a service to component.

Here is my code, I tried to copy it from tuto Tour of Heroes, but it doesn't work

LoginComponent:

```
this.authenticationService.login(this.f.email.value, this.f.password.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error.error);
          this.error = error;
          this.loading = false;
        });
  }
```

AuthenticationService:

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>('https://api.kz-api.test/auth/login', {email: email, password: password}, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        map((res: any) => {
          if (res && res.token) {
            this.setToken(TOKEN);
          }
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError('login', []))
      );
  }
```

It should return an observable but in component, `console.log(data);` gives `[]`

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: in your map - return the response, after if condition. example  return { res: res.json() }

Comment: What does `res` print inside `login()`?

Comment: inside login(), I have all the info: {code:200, message: 'OK'}

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are using the `map` operator rather than using the `tap` operator. Right now you are mapping over the response and not returning anything so the data comes out to `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning any response data from the service.
 Try this:

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<any>('https://api.kz-api.test/auth/login', {email: email, password: password}, httpOptions)
          .pipe(
            map((res: any) => {
              if (res && res.token) {
                this.setToken(TOKEN);
              }
              return {
                  res: res.json()
             };
            }),
            catchError(this.handleError('login', []))
          );
      }
```

Comment: are you getting data from service